# WGAN outputs "NaN" for loss when dealing with large datasets in TF 2.6

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I am working on applying a Wasserstein GAN to a large dataset. I used to be working on a computing server in my research institute, but it is quite small and so I started using a larger one. I discovered after some digging that the server in my institute uses NP 1.18.5 and TF 2.3.1, whereas the larger one uses NP 1.19.5 and TF 2.6.0, if these are relevant at all.

The models I used on the smaller server worked fine (they suffered mode collapse, but the code worked is what I mean), but as soon as I started running stuff on the larger one, I started getting `NaN` for the loss of both the generator and the critic. I investigated the issue a bit, and it seems to be tied to the amount of data my WGAN is processing: once I start using ~6.5G of data, it returns `NaN`s, but below that threshold it seems to perform just fine. My total dataset is about 9G. It outputs `NaN` after the very first training iteration, so I don't think the problem is exploding gradients, but I am no specialist.

I have tried implementing batch normalzation both before and after the activation of the critic, as well as value clipping, but neither seem to affect the output on large datasets.

Full code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/2iJ0gQ5j (it's messy, I know)

Here is minimum workable example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import csv
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import glob
import math
from pathlib import Path

from tensorflow.keras import backend
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Dropout, BatchNormalization, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.constraints import Constraint



# implementation of wasserstein loss
def wasserstein_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return backend.mean(y_true * y_pred)

# clip model weights to a given hypercube
class ClipConstraint(Constraint):
    # set clip value when initialized
    def __init__(self, clip_value):
        self.clip_value = clip_value
 
    # clip model weights to hypercube
    def __call__(self, weights):
        return backend.clip(weights, -self.clip_value, self.clip_value)
 
    # get the config
    def get_config(self):
        return {'clip_value': self.clip_value}

# generate points in latent space as input for the generator
def generate_latent_points(latent_dim, n_samples):
    # generate points in the latent space
    x_input = np.random.randn(latent_dim * n_samples)
    # reshape into a batch of inputs for the network
    x_input = x_input.reshape(n_samples, latent_dim)
    return x_input

def generate_real_samples(data, n) :
    idx = np.random.choice(data.shape[0], n, replace=False)
    return data[idx, :], -np.ones((n,1))

def generate_fake_samples(g_model, latent, n) :
    return g_model(generate_latent_points(latent, n)), np.ones((n,1))



SNP_dir = "/my/work/dir/in/"
SNP_vcf_list = glob.glob(SNP_dir+"*.csv")
nstep = 2500
ncritstep = 5


### READ INPUT
sampleIDs = []
sampleData = {}
meaningful = []
linesperfile = []

## data is stored in multiple files, so it is read as a dictionary then converted into an array
for SNP_vcf in SNP_vcf_list :
    n = 0
    with open(SNP_vcf, newline='') as csvfile:
        csvread = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';',  quotechar='"')
        for myline in csvread: #reads csvfile line by line, storing array of cells into myline
            if(myline[0][0] == '#'):
                myline[0] = myline[0][2:]
                for mycell in myline : 
                    if mycell not in sampleIDs :
                        sampleIDs.append(mycell)
                        sampleData[mycell] = []
            else :
                n+=1
                ## some lines contain all 0s, so they are removed here.
                mybool = np.std(np.asarray(myline).astype(np.float32)) != 0
                meaningful.append(mybool)
                i=0
                for mycell in myline : 
                    sampleData[sampleIDs[i]].append(float(mycell))
                    i+=1
    linesperfile.append(n)
input_size = sum(meaningful)
print("Read "+str(input_size)+" meaningful encoded variables for "+str(len(sampleIDs))+" samples")



real = []
for k, v in sampleData.items() :
    real.append(np.array(v)[meaningful])
real = np.array(real)
print(real.shape)
del(sampleData)




### CREATE CRITIC

hidden_c_1_size = math.ceil(input_size/10)
hidden_c_2_size = math.ceil(input_size/50)
hidden_c_3_size = math.ceil(input_size/100)

print("First hidden critic layer size: "+str(hidden_c_1_size))
print("Second hidden critic layer size: "+str(hidden_c_2_size))
print("Third hidden critic layer size: "+str(hidden_c_3_size))

hidden_g_1_size = math.ceil(input_size/10)
hidden_g_2_size = math.ceil(input_size/50)
hidden_g_3_size = math.ceil(input_size/100)

print("First hidden generator layer size: "+str(hidden_g_3_size))
print("Second hidden generator layer size: "+str(hidden_g_2_size))
print("Third hidden generator layer size: "+str(hidden_g_1_size))

const = ClipConstraint(0.01)

critic_input = Input(shape=(input_size, ))
c_hidden_1 = Dense(hidden_c_1_size, kernel_constraint=const)(critic_input)
c_bnorm_1 = BatchNormalization()(c_hidden_1)
c_act_1 = Activation("relu")(c_bnorm_1)
c_drop_1 = Dropout(0.4)(c_act_1)
c_hidden_2 = Dense(hidden_c_2_size, kernel_constraint=const)(c_drop_1)
c_bnorm_2 = BatchNormalization()(c_hidden_2)
c_act_2 = Activation("relu")(c_bnorm_2)
c_drop_2 = Dropout(0.4)(c_act_2)
c_hidden_3 = Dense(hidden_c_3_size, kernel_constraint=const)(c_drop_2)
c_bnorm_3 = BatchNormalization()(c_hidden_3)
c_act_3 = Activation("relu")(c_bnorm_3)
critic_output = Dense(1, activation='linear')(c_act_3)

critic = Model(critic_input, critic_output)

opt = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.00005, clipvalue=0.01)
critic.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=wasserstein_loss)

### CREATE GENERATOR

latent_dim_size = 1000
generator_input = Input(latent_dim_size)
g_hidden_1 = Dense(hidden_g_3_size, activation='relu')(generator_input)
g_drop_1 = Dropout(0.4)(g_hidden_1)
g_hidden_2 = Dense(hidden_g_2_size, activation='relu')(g_drop_1)
g_drop_2 = Dropout(0.4)(g_hidden_2)
g_hidden_3 = Dense(hidden_g_1_size, activation='relu')(g_drop_2)
generator_output = Dense(input_size, activation='relu')(g_hidden_3)

generator = Model(generator_input, generator_output)

critic.trainable = False
GAN = Sequential()
GAN.add(generator)
GAN.add(critic)
opt = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.00005, clipvalue=0.01)
GAN.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=wasserstein_loss)





c_history = []
g_history = []

for i in range(nstep) :
    ## Train critic more than generator
    c_loss = 0
    for j in range(ncritstep) :
        critic.trainable = True
        x_real, y_real = generate_real_samples(real, 1000)
        x_fake, y_fake = generate_fake_samples(generator, latent_dim_size, 1000)
        c_loss += critic.train_on_batch(x_real, y_real)
        c_loss += critic.train_on_batch(x_fake, y_fake)
    c_history.append(c_loss)
    critic.trainable = False
    x_gan = generate_latent_points(latent_dim_size, 1000)
    y_gan = -np.ones((1000,1))
    g_loss = GAN.train_on_batch(x_gan, y_gan)
    g_history.append(g_loss)
    if (i+1)%10 == 0 :
        print(">"+str(i+1)+": c_loss= "+str(c_loss)+"; g_loss= "+str(g_loss))
        
        
print("Training finished! Moving on to output")

## output removed for simplicity's sake
```

As for my data, as I've mentioned, it's quite large. What I can tell you about it is that there are close to 100 000 dimensions for about 2500 samples, all of them floats. What I'm trying to do here is not as important as the problem I'm encountering imo. If you really want some of the data to see what it looks like, I can find a way to save some in the cloud or something. As I've said, it used to work on that dataset on the smaller server, and it works when working with under 70K dimensions, but it produces `NaN`s when run on the full dataset when using TF 2.6. Why is this happening? I can't seem to diagnose my neural network with the information available to me.

**UPDATE** - As per gobrewers' suggestion, I added `tf.debugging.enable_check_numerics()`, here is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "encoded_wgan.py", line 272, in <module>
    c_loss += critic.train_on_batch(x, y)
  File "/tools/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1856, in train_on_batch
    logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "/tools/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 885, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/tools/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 950, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "/tools/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3040, in __call__
    filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/tools/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1964, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "/tools/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 596, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/tools/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 138, in execute_with_callbacks
    tensors = quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
  File "/tools/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  

!!! Detected Infinity or NaN in output 0 of graph op "IteratorGetNext" (# of outputs: 2) !!!
  dtype: <dtype: 'float32'>
  shape: (2000, 99557)

  Input tensor: Tensor("iterator:0", shape=(), dtype=resource)
  Graph name: "train_function"

  Stack trace of op's creation ("->": inferred user code):
    + encoded_wgan.py (L272) <module>
 -> |   c_loss += critic.train_on_batch(x, y)
    + ...b/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py (L1856) train_on_batch
 -> |   logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    + ...e-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py (L885) __call__
    |   result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    + ...e-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py (L950) _call
    |   return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    + .../site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py (L3038) __call__
    |   filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
    + .../site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py (L3463) _maybe_define_function
    |   graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
    + .../site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py (L3308) _create_graph_function
    |   capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
    + ...packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py (L1007) func_graph_from_py_func
    |   func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    + ...e-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py (L668) wrapped_fn
    |   out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    + ...packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py (L990) wrapper
    |   user_requested=True,
    + ...b/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py (L853) train_function
 -> |   return step_function(self, iterator)
    + ...b/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py (L841) step_function
 -> |   data = next(iterator)
    + ...ackages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py (L761) __next__
    |   return self._next_internal()
    + ...ackages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py (L738) _next_internal
    |   output_shapes=self._flat_output_shapes)
    + ...-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py (L2750) iterator_get_next
    |   output_shapes=output_shapes, name=name)
    + ...ages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py (L750) _apply_op_helper
    |   attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
    + ...packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py (L601) _create_op_internal
    |   compute_device)
    + ...7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py (L3569) _create_op_internal
    |   op_def=op_def)
    + ...7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py (L2045) __init__
    |   self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack_for_node(self._c_op)

 : Tensor had NaN values
     [[node IteratorGetNext/CheckNumericsV2 (defined at encoded_wgan.py:272) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2000]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

(note: that `L272` is the very first `train_on_batch()` I call in the full script.)

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, you haven't asked a question.

Comment: @gobrewers14 Done, however the question of the data still stands

Comment: I'd add [tf.debugging.enable_check_numerics](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/debugging/enable_check_numerics) to your training script and see if you can pinpoint where your `NaN`s are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

## I'm blind

I have `NaN`s in my data, just at some very specific locations. So when I load only a part of my data, I don't include them, but I do with the full dataset.

**CHECK YOUR DATA FOOLS**